ADB Backup without Unlock Notification
I'm trying to use adb with a device running Android 11.
I confirmed it's connected and recognized via adb devices, but I can't get the actual app backup because the device does not display the usual unlock and backup notification screen (it's a Chinese device that might have some custom changes).
Is there any way to force the backup without the notification screen?
EDIT: The device generally doesn't have a lock screen or unlock pin, this might be part of the issue

You can check the backup command implementation on the device by executing adb shell bu help. If adb shell works in general, but this commands fails, then the backup system on your device is bugged.

@Robert 'bu help' displays the usual help dialogue (backup [-user USER_ID] etc.)

Ok, then at least but is present and works. Had once a Lenovo tablet where bu was totally screwed... Then I would recommend to continue using directly bu so may be you get a different message and learn what is going wrong.

@Robert do you have a suggestion for the commands I should try? As per my edit it's potentially an issue with the device running a modified A11 version that doesn't have a lock screen.
